# Kissing the mezuzah before netilat yadayim in the morning

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, mezuzah, kissing

Is it permissible to kiss the mezuzah in the morning before you wash your hands (netilat yadayim)?

Comment: With your hand, or directly with your mouth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rabbi Tzvi Yanir Shlita](http://www.ypt.co.il/ask_show.asp?id=140128) says that since the original custom is to only kiss the Mezuza upon entering and leaving the house, one should not kiss the Mezuza of his room in the morning prior to Netilas Yadayim.

Comment: What if you have to leave your house before washing your hands?

Comment: Doing so would just create a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Most likely that is not the question as most people would not leave their house prior to Netilas Yadayim, yet it is more likely that one goes out of a bedroom on the way to washing Netilas Yadayim.