# (Not) kissing the mezuzah

Tags: minhag, mezuzah, samson-raphael-hirsch

Kissing one’s mezuzah seems to be an almost universally accepted custom nowadays, at least among Ashkenazim. However, I once heard it was the minhag of R. Hirsch to simply look at it and meditate on its content, without touching the physical box, whenever one passes a door with a mezuzah attached.

Nevertheless, I’ve never found the actual source of said practice, and now I’m afraid it might not be true at all. Maybe it was just my wishful thinking to have an established tradition that was against kissing mezuzot, as I find the act a bit unhygienic.

Any ideas regarding the factually of it all?

Comment: While AZ 11a describes Onkelos touching the mezuza, and some acharonim mention this as a basis for the custom to touch the mezuza when entering or exiting a home (e.g. Rama YD 285:2), this custom isn't universal. I recall a story where R' Yerucham Gorelick questioned why a student kissed the mezuza, and he colorfully observed that it's not required to kiss every mitzva. The Chazon Ish (*Orchos Rabbeinu*, vol. III, pg. 164) and the Maharil Diskin (*Salmas Chayim* 380) would merely look at the mezuza as they walked through a doorway, and R' YE Henkin suggested blowing a kiss towards the mezuza.

Comment: See more details in [this article](https://outorah.org/p/33320/) from R' Ari Zivotofsky. Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12051/ . See also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21975/ and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/74120/ .

Comment: Welcome to MY! Regarding the recent epidemic this question was widely discussed, and most pointed out that it's not an obligation only a nice custom.

Comment: I don't think the Gr"a was in favour of the physical adulation of mitzvah artefacts.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Interesting: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75283/15256

Comment: @Fred Appreciate the source-dense answer. I was wrong on using “universal”. “Widespread” would be a proper term. I generally don’t dance with the Chazon Ish because he’s not too close to my hashkafah, but I guess I’ll have to rely on him. I’m S&P, so having the Arizal as the one who popularised the kissing custom is already good enough reason for me to stay away from it. 

I ended up asking a friend who’s very well versed in the Portuguese tradition and he sent me a snippet of the [KST](https://i.imgur.com/D9MKNTo.jpg) on the matter. Overall, similar opinions compared to what you mentioned.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I thank you for the warm greeting! I’m well aware of the many threads on the subject that’ve sprung in the last couple of years. I took a quick overlook at them, and since they don’t provide an answer to my search for a R. Hirsch quotation, I decided to make this post (sorry if it was the wrong move).

Comment: After looking some more, since no one provided a source for it, I’m almost convinced this comment of R. Hirsch was a figment of my imagination, I’m afraid.

I try my best at being shomer Torah uMitsvot, but I’m afraid my general Hebrew literacy and knowledge of halachic terms and abbreviations are exceedingly poor. Do excuse me for my at times slow grasp of reality.

Comment: @Mich I commented on Grapke's comment. No worries, your question is perfectly fine, hopefully someone will be able to give the answer you need.

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe would touch the mezuzah and other holy objects without kissing them. But he spoke favorably about the custom of children kissing the mezuzah before bed.